# background color full page

Tags: html, css, colors, background

[image]My current code seems to make a pattern instead of covering the entire page. How do I make it to cover the entire page instead of a pattern like depiction?

```html
<style>
  body {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #211B53, #ECE3E6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  #para1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 600%;
    color: black;
  }
  
  div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
</style>

<p id="para1"> ARTWORK</p>
<div class="absolute"> All sales final. </div>
```

Comment: instead of body height:100% set body min-height:100vh;

Comment: or just set 100% height for html

Answer (score 2):

When using gradient make sure you use correct css to go along with it

```css
 body {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #211B53, #ECE3E6);
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100vh;
    background-size: cover; 
  }
  
  #para1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 600%;
    color: black;
  }
  
  div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<p id="para1"> ARTWORK</p>
<div class="absolute"> All sales final. </div>
```

You're good to go!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `width` and `height` to `100%` on body, instead set them to `100vw` and `100vh` respectively:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #211B53, #ECE3E6);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#para1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 600%;
  color: black;
}

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="para1"> ARTWORK</p>
<div class="absolute"> All sales final. </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need to do is change the height value of the body from percentage to viewport height.

```
height: 100vh;
```

you can read more about viewport units [here](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
body { 
background-size: cover; 
   }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations along with your code, so that future users can follow your ideas/code more easily. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23348793)