# Why background color is not displaying properly in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I am new to angular as in just starting. I have built this small angular app and when I edit the style.css file and add a background-color property to the body tag only the section around my form is getting colored and not the whole page (refer to the image to understand better). Can someone explain to me why?? Any explanation would be appreciated.
this is the code snippet from the style.css file

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "bulma/css/bulma.css";
body {
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.passbox {
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et2o5.png)

Comment: Try to add your background color to `html` and `body` .

Comment: Your form is most likely overwriting the body's `background-color` with its own styles.

Comment: we need more code

Answer (score 0):

Because the height of your `body` stops at that point (because there is no more content) so as a result, the body will not fit the whole screen, instead you could use `min-height: 100vh` for `<body>`

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "bulma/css/bulma.css";

body {
  background-color: burlywood;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks i will try that

Answer (score 0):

You will notice, upon inspection, that the body does not actually fill the entire screen. So, what you need to do, is find a way to make it (the `body`) full.

1. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730007/14492841), adding `height: 100vh;` may do it.
2. According to [this link](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), adding `background-size: cover;` can fix it

While I do not have the full answer myself, I hope that by heading you in the right direction you'll be able to refine your search and find what you're looking for :-)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks i will try that